# Bash scripting to create hosts file from amazon api output

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, hosts

I m newbie in scripting. My requirement is to create a /etc/hosts file as below from the output of aws api.

```
Hostname PrivateIP

abc x.y.x.z

cde a.b.c.c
```

and so on.

I have the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=abc
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=cde
export EC2_URL=https://url.com
source ~/.bashrc
ec2-describe-instances --filter "group-name=mygroup" > /tmp/info
name=$(cat /tmp/info| grep 'Hostname' | cut -f 5)
ip=$(cat /tmp/info| grep 'INSTANCE' | cut -f 18)
echo -e $name"\t"$ip
```

currenltly the output is in one line.
I m sure i need a for loop. But not sure how to do it.
Please advice.

Comment: Should post more info on what /tmp/info looks like for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a for loop on name variable, try something like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
name=(`cat /tmp/info| grep 'Hostname' | cut -f 5`)
unset IFS

# For loop based on name
for i in "${name[@]}"
do
   # process each name ($i)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the exact format of the ec2-describe-instances command, but here's an easy way to process multiple lines of output that are formatted into fields separated by tabs:

```
input=/tmp/info
while read field1 field2 field3 ...; do        # fieldx variables map to each field in the output
    # process the fields you need
done < "$input"
```